# Octave 2d Plotting time series - line not connecting markers (precision error)

Tags: octave, timestamp, plot

Relevant info: Octave version...5.2.0
pkgs used: io-2.6.2
tablicious-0.3.5
Ubuntu version- 20.04.4 LTS

Hi! I'm reading timestamp and temperature data from an xlsx spreadsheet into Octave. I'm running into an interesting issue however. I'm able to plot the data, with the dateticks, and temperature data (markers) in the correct locations. Interestingly the (Line) seems to be close, but not actually connecting the markers. I'm not sure if I'm missing something silly, or experiencing a bug. Thanks so much!  [image]
[image]

clear all;

clc;

pkg load tablicious;

pkg load io;

[a,b]=xlsread('D10000007266C941_011522.xlsx','D10000007266C941_011522','A21:A221');
temp=xlsread('D10000007266C941_011522.xlsx','D10000007266C941_011522','C21:C221');

% The code above successfully read dates into octave!

date=datenum([a,b],'mm/dd/yy HH:MM:SS PM');

timeformat='mm/dd/yy';

figure(1)

grid on;

hold on;

plot (date,temp, "linestyle",'-',"marker",'o',"color",'b');

datetick ('x',timeformat,'keeplimits');

set(gca, 'linewidth', 2)

Answer (score 1):

So it appears to be a limitation of the OpenGL graphics toolkit. It lacks precision!! Oh dear... The following link explains it better than I will here, so I wont waste anyone's time.

https://docs.octave.org/v7.1.0/Precision-issues.html

See the following results of a "work around"..

The bad

[image]

The Much improved results! Don't you worry, its only 2000 years off...hee hee
[image]